# Representing a maze

Tags: c, data-structures, robotics

How would I represent this maze, so that I can run dijkstras algorithm on it?

[Maze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEbS4.png)

I've been looking around, and the most common representations seem to be the adjacency matrix and adjacency list.

So:

1) What should my vertices be?

2) What should my edges be?

Because it will be a race, the maze is not known before hand.

3) How do I update my matrix?

Note: We are given a chance to explore the maze, so I'll be using a wall follower along with a mapper that calculates the distance the robot is from the start, but not sure how this would all translate to be of any use when building the matrix.

Comment: You don't need an adjacency matrix *or* list here; since it's a square grid, the adjacencies are implied by the coordinates. Have a 2D array of Squares where each Square stores which sides the walls are on.

Comment: If one of the answers answers your question, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkbox next to it.

Answer (score -1):

For example, you can declaes a room structure as:

```
struct tRoom {
    enum {
        NORTH,
        EAST,
        SOUTH,
        WEST
    };
    int walls[4]; /* status: 0 -- The wall is open
                             1 -- The wall is close
                   */
    ...
}

/* A room in the game looks like:

       ____ The wall is close and cannot walk through
      |
      |
      v
   +-----+
   |     |
   |
   |     |
   +-   -+
      ^
      |
      |____   The wall is open and can walk through

 */

 /* A maze looks like :

   +-----+-----+-----+
   |     |     |     |
   |  *              |
   |     |     |     |
   +-   -+-----+-   -+
   |     |     |     |
   |     |     |     |
   |     |     |     |
   +-----+-----+-----+
*/
```

And declare your maze as:

```
struct tRoom[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

Initially the robot is put to the starting room (which has a star).

Then the player can cotrol movement of the robot by keypress or other devices.
       The game ends when the robot reaches the goal room.

Surely you can find a path by some algorithm and then guide the robot to the goal.

Comment: How does the movement of the robot get translated into this?

Comment: @ScottHunter What does that mean?

Comment: The path will be composed of a sequence of directions. The robot can walk in the specified direction.

Comment: You know this from the almost empty description of the robot?

Comment: @PanRuochen it is not clear what your definition of a room is (all of the examples did not have any, for example)

Comment: Just read my updated answer if you do not understand room, maze and robot well.

Comment: @PanRuochen I believe it is you who do not understand the difference between a robot and program to simulate a robot.

Comment: what differs then?

Answer (score -2):

I would define a struct that represents each junction of the maze as a node, with each corridor branching out as a vertex in the form of a pointer to another node. Something along the following ought to do it:

```
#define MAX_VERTEXES_PER_NODE 4

struct junction;

struct corridor {
  int weight;
  struct junction *other_end;
};

struct junction {
  struct corridor junctions[MAX_VERTEXES_PER_NODE];
};
```

It is straightforward to apply Dijkstra (or any other graph theory algorithm) to this representation.

Comment: The problem, then, is how to tell which junction the robot is at; in particular, detecting when it has revisited a junction.

Comment: That's nothing special to this case. You can add whatever meta data you need to the junction struct (bool, red/black color enum, whatever). The question was not about how to implement Dijsktra.

Comment: How does this information get from the robot to your data structure?

Comment: The question was how to represent the Maze. How to map the maze is a different question, unrelated to the one asked.

Comment: So it doesn't matter if it is not possible to populate the representation from the information available; good to know.